# Universal references with functions

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, rvalue

What is the type of "univ" in the code below?

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& univ) {
    // ??
}

int sum(int a, int b) {
 return a+b;   
}

int main() {

    func(sum);

}
```

I didn't know that universal references also worked with functions. Is `func(sum);` equivalent to `func(&sum);` or is the rvalue reference binding itself to something else than a simple pointer?

Comment: I feel like we just had that question... [edit] Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31125447

Comment: You can check types with following trick `template<typename> void type_is();`  [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77c1704901003313)

Comment: `univ` is of type `int(&)(int, int)` in that instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to put this into more words...

The type is reference to function taking two `int`s and returning and `int`

or, as a comment says: `int(&)(int, int)`