# Reference to global functions not deduced correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, template-argument-deduction

I am using gcc 12.2 and find that the following code compiles and produces weird results [try it in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tsnz668cq). (P.S. Switching to clang shows the same result)

```
#include <iostream>
void global() { /*std::cout << "global()" << std::endl;*/ }

template <typename T> // universal reference
void invoke(T&& func, const std::string& tag) { 
    if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        std::cout << "rvalue reference " << tag << std::endl;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        std::cout << "lvalue reference " << tag << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "non-reference " << tag << std::endl;
    }
    func(); 
}

template <typename T>
struct Test {
    Test(T&& x, const std::string& tag) // rvalue reference, not universal reference 
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T>) {
            std::cout << "rvalue reference " << tag << std::endl;
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {
            std::cout << "lvalue reference " << tag << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "non-reference " << tag << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int && x = 3;
    using RRef = void (&&)();
    RRef rref = global;
    using LRef = void (&)();
    LRef lref = global;

    std::cout << "RRef       is rvalue reference " << std::is_rvalue_reference_v<RRef> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "rref       is rvalue reference " << std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(rref)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "move(rref) is rvalue reference " << std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(std::move(rref))> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x          is rvalue reference " << std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(x)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "move(x)    is rvalue reference " << std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(std::move(x))> << std::endl;

    std::cout << "==== invoke ==== " << std::endl;
    invoke(global, "global");
    invoke(rref, "rref");
    invoke(std::move(rref), "rref2");
    invoke(lref, "lref");
    invoke(std::move(lref), "lref2");

    std::cout << "==== Test ==== " << std::endl;
    Test(global, "global");
    Test(rref, "rref");
    Test(std::move(rref), "rref2");
    Test(lref, "lref");
    Test(std::move(lref), "lref2");

    std::cout << "==== Test int ==== " << std::endl;
    // Test(x, "x");  // cannot bind lvalue to rvalue-reference
    Test(std::move(x), "move(x)");
}
```

The output is as following for gcc 12.2:

```
RRef       is rvalue reference 1
rref       is rvalue reference 1
move(rref) is rvalue reference 0   // why is this no longer rvalue reference
x          is rvalue reference 1
move(x)    is rvalue reference 1
==== invoke ==== 
lvalue reference global  // why are they all lvalue reference
lvalue reference rref
lvalue reference rref2
lvalue reference lref
lvalue reference lref2
==== Test ==== 
non-reference global  // why they are non-reference
non-reference rref
non-reference rref2
non-reference lref
non-reference lref2
==== Test int ==== 
non-reference move(x)
```

Could you please explain why we get the following output:

1. `std::move(rref)` is an lvalue reference while `std::move(x)` is an rvalue reference
2. when passing the functions to `invoke`, which accepts universal reference, the deduced type are all lvalue-reference, indicating lvalue references are passed to the `invoke`
3. when passing the functions to `Test`, which accepts only rvalue references, the various inputs are all accepted, indicating they are all rvalue references.

Passing reference of `int` behaves normal, while passing reference of function behaves quite wierd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Even though `std::move(x)` is an rvalue reference, `std::move(rref)` is an lvalue because it is a special case in the standard. From C++14 standard [[expr.call/p10]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.call#10):

   > **A function call is an lvalue if the result type is** an lvalue reference type or **an rvalue reference to function type**, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.

   This is explained in detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31125846/2059689) answer.
2. When passing the values to `invoke()`, you pass them either

   - Using their variable names (which are lvalues):

     ```
     invoke(global, "global");
     invoke(rref, "rref");
     ```
   - Or by means of `std::move(ref-to-function)` like here:

     ```
     invoke(std::move(rref), "rref2");
     ```

     This is also an lvalue because of a special case mentioned in (1).

   Thus, the template argument binds to lvalue in all cases.
3. Please note that your `Test` constructor prints info about the template argument type `T` and not about the type of the parameter `x` (which is `T&&`). That's why you see "non-reference" where you expect "rvalue reference". If we replace the code to print info about `decltype(x)` instead of `T` we get the expected "rvalue reference" result.

   As to why the rvalue reference in `Test` constructor accepts the lvalue inputs. It's again a special case in the standard that permits binding of rvalue references to function lvalues. From C++14 standard  [[over.ics.ref/3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over.ics.ref#3):

   > Except for an implicit object parameter, for which see [over.match.funcs], a standard conversion sequence cannot be formed if it requires binding an lvalue reference other than a reference to a non-volatile const type to an rvalue or **binding an rvalue reference to an lvalue other than a function lvalue**.

In any case, uses of *rvalue-reference-to-function* are quite rare and obscure, usually lvalue reference is enough for most needs (although [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7017396/2059689) is one example when rvalue reference is needed).

Comment: And for 3. it is also important that there is another exception for function types in reference binding that allows lvalues to bind to rvalue references.

Comment: @user17732522 I think your comment make the answer complete. From the first two items of the answer, I understood that all the five cases `global/lref/...` are lvalues. Then I cannot understand "why they can be bound to the parameter of constructor `Test(T&&)`, which only accept rvalue reference" until I read your comment. Could you please give the source/link of this exception?

Comment: @vvv444 thanks for your reply, which is very helpful. Now I got that the parameters passed to `invoke` are all lvalue references. Could you please also add some to explain why the these lvalue references are accepted by `Test`'s constructor which needs to be rvalue reference?

Comment: Thanks. The added quote indicated that "const lvalue reference can bind to rvalue reference" and "rvalue reference can bind to function lvalue".

Comment: @doraemon The answer now provides the quote from the standard that permits overload resolution to succeed under these circumstances. Then you only need the "or function lvalue" part of https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3.1 to actually define the reference binding and the behavior is fully explained.